# How to exclude one element from selecting entire body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript

my question is:

I have a context menu that should disappear whenever you click anywhere else but one row in that context menu.

id = "except" is a li element within my context menu(which is a ul element). I try to exclude that element from selection of the entire body but it does not work like that because except is burried deep in multiple other parent elements

body->.wrapper->.content-wrapper->.content->#contextMenu->#except

```
$("body").not("#except")
            .one("click",
                () => {
                        $("#contextMenu").hide();
                        $("body").detach("#contextMenu");
                });
```

Is there a way to specify the path from body to #except element inside .not() function? I tried multiple things without success

I can make my way from body to contextMenu like this $("body>>>>"), but the problem is, my click function will only be called when I click somewhere inside contextMenu.

thank you!

EDIT: important info: These lines of code are inside a contextMenuHandler function so I think I need to disable #except somewhere before that click function and that's why I try .not() function

Comment: did you try `.stop()` ? My opinion is that you have to stop the event propagation for when the user clicks on the `#except` in order to prevent the bubbling effect. In JavaScript, if I am not wrong, an event is traveling up to the root element once it is triggered. By stopping the propagation when a click is made in the `#except` you will prevent the context menu to disappear when it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your time Merianos. I can't seem to wrap my head around that .stop() method. Could you please explain, where would I use it in my code? I tried to put this inside the function
if (event.target == document.getElementById("except")) $("#except").stop();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$("body").one("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.id !== 'except') {
        $("#contextMenu").hide();
        $("body").detach("#contextMenu");
    }
});
```

`$("body").not("#except")` will select `body` tags those don't have `except` id. Which will not work in your case.

**Update:**

If I didn't misunderstood your problem then this will work for you

```
$("body").on("click.contextMenu", (event) => {
    if (event.target.id !== 'except') {
        $("#contextMenu").hide();
        $("body").detach("#contextMenu");
        $("body").off("click.contextMenu");
    }
});
```

What I did is,
Instead of binding event by `one` binded it with `on`. Also specified a namespace.

The reason behind specifying namespace is we can then unbind this event using the namespace.

I have used `contextMenu` here, you can specify any name.

Comment: thank you sir! The problem with this solution, at least in my code, is that even though clicking on #except won't make contextMenu go away, however "it counts as a click", which means that if I click somewhere else again, contextMenu will stay there

I forgot to mention very important thing. These lines of code are inside a contextMenuhandler function. And that's why I need to get rid of #except before click event function

Comment: @NevilleLobotom updated my answer. I am still confuse, why you have mention `contextMenuHandler` function and what do you mean get rid of #except? Can you elaborate this if my updated answer is not working for you

Comment: it works!!!! Thank you very much for using your free time to help a stranger. :-)